# How can I send an email in C# using cPanel email account

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, cpanel, smtpclient

I have a cpanel email account and I want to use that account to send emails through my web application written in C#. The error I receive is Connection timeout. The code works well with gmail but it does not with cpanel. The cpanel manual instructs me to use port 465 or port 2525 to send an email. Can someone please help me with it.

```
        using var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient ();
        smtp.Host = server;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential ();
        NetworkCred.UserName = from;
        NetworkCred.Password = password;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 2525;
        smtp.Send (email);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to send email from your domain address try your raw domain as host address. i had this problem too. that was because of host address in cPanel and plesk i have to enter my domain url as the host address.

Comment: I am sending from the domain address provided in the cPanel details. But when I try to telnet the smtp with the port I am getting connection timed out